HarmonyLib question (change bytes in run time)
enter image description hereI'm trying to modify a real-time game's PlayerDamageCalc method so that it returns a fixed value of 40. I'm using HarmonyLib to apply patches and Extreme Injector to inject the DLL into the game process.
Here is the code for the method I want to modify in run time:
public float PlayerDamageCalc()
{
    float num = this.characterBaseDamage + this.weaponDamage;
    if (this.playerRanged && this.playerBulletDamageDecreasePercent > 1f)
    {
        num = num / this.playerBulletDamageDecreasePercent + num * 0.1f;
    }
    return num;
}

My intention is to override the return of this method to always be 40. However, despite the log file being created on the desktop, debug is not currently showing useful information.
My current configuration is as follows:
IDE: Visual Studio (in Portuguese)
Injector: Extreme Injector (generic but functional)
DLL editor: dnSpy
I am having difficulty identifying why the change is not being applied. Any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this?
